# Junit & Allure Reporting 2 - How can we programmatically set Issue and TmsLink?

Tags: java, allure

the standard use of these works great, @TmsLink("foo") @Issue("bar) *However* when using a dataProvider scenario, how can I programmatically set these values on each iteration of the @Test method?

Each csv entry for my test data will contain both an Id for TmsLink and Issue, how can I make each test set its own for good reporting purposes? We can do it with SeverityLevel which looks like a simple enum, however Issue/TmsLink are interfaces with @Target at Method/Type only

```
 SeverityLevel severity = severityLevel.CRITICAL;


package io.qameta.allure;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * Used to link tests with issues.
 */
@Documented
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Repeatable(Issues.class)
public @interface Issue {

    String value();

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to anyone coming along to this at a later stage, I figured it out by overriding the annotation values at runtime, its not amazing by any stretch but it works, I wrote up a blog post on the subject:

https://symonk.github.io/2017-10-26-overriding-allure-reporting-annotational-values-at-runtime-for-issue-tmslink-displayname/